# Google map interactive features no longer work on desktop

Tags: windows-10-desktop

Can no longer get any feature of Google Maps to work on my desktop in Chrome and Firefox (works in Edge). Happened once and returned to normal when I re-installed Chrome. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think this is the right forum to ask for support on interoperability between two Google products. Either Google have some better forum somewhere (and you should go there instead) or they are uninterested in supporting their stuff and that's what you get. See also: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Ever tried getting customer service from Google? Don't waste your time. Just thought someone might have encountered a similar problem and found a viable solution. Thanks anyway.